# Problems with catching eval() SyntaxError using cookiecutter

Tags: python, syntax-error, eval, try-except, cookiecutter

I have a problem in Python (2.7) - I have a cookiecutter project that prompts for input (via CLI) and then generates my project based on that input.

One of my fields is a description, and I've seen that adding quote marks in, i.e. 'Hello this is "my" description' will cause a Syntax error when I pass it through eval:

```
File "/var/folders/4b/gzszrl3d5fn1q7vvv05s63vmf014cj/T/tmpnJWgqK.py", line 53
    parameters = eval("{u'description': u'Hello this is "my" description'}")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ERROR: Stopping generation because pre_gen_project hook script didn't exit successfully
```

The section of code executing this is:

```
try:
    parameters = eval("{{ cookiecutter }}")
except:
    print('An error occurred!')
    sys.exit(1)
```

My problem is the code never enters the `except` clause, so I have no chance to exit gracefully.

Is there any way I can handle this better?

P.S. I know I could sanitise the input using some Jinja2 filters, but am looking for a solution that lets me handle an error without altering the input.

Comment: This won't reach the except statement as it is a `SyntaxError` meaning that the error is found while parsing, which occurs before running your code. So you need to get rid of any `SyntaxError`s for your except to work.

Answer (score 1):

`eval("{u'description': u'Hello this is "my" description'}")` is your problem.

You have to escape `"` between `my`.

`eval("{u'description': u'Hello this is \"my\" description'}")`

Comment: Hey @Arount, my problem is that I don't have control of user input and don't expect people to escape their own text. I can escape it myself using escape/replace Jinja2 filters, but can't edit the input due to how the project is laid out. I'm looking for a way to handle the error gracefully without altering the input.